# React <Select> element in a for loop issue

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, select

I'm new in this coding world. Can you help me please ?

I have this select element with a for loop:

```js
{servicerate.map(dep=>
 <select name="Country"  className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
   <option selected>Select the Country</option>
   for (let servicerateid in servicerateid)
      {
      <option value="{servicerateID}" onChange={this.updateCountryChoice}> {dep.country} </option>
       }
 </select>
)}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BkaT.png)

and I'm getting this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnqBk.png)

Anyone please ?
This should be obvious to you guys, but for me it's being complicated.
Thanks

I tried several ways to do the for loop but without success

Comment: please share code instead of screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
{servicerate.map(dep=>
<select value="{servicerateID}" onChange={this.updateCountryChoice} name="Country"  className="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
<option selected>Select the Country</option>
    for (let servicerateid in servicerateid)
        {
        <option> {dep.country} </option>
        }
</select>
)}
```